# How to assign a different Joomla template style to subpages?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, articles, extensions, menu-parameters

How to make the sub articles have different template style and not inherit the one assigned to their parent category?

Let's say that I have news category which uses the default template style. How can I assign a different template style the single articles of that category.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your template is not in the list of the non-compatible templates/frameworks of this extension, I would suggest you to go with the [**Regular Labs Advanced Template Manager**](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedtemplatemanager#free-vs-pro).

> Advanced Template Manager is an extension that changes the way your Template manager works.
>
> With Joomla you can normally only assign template styles to certain menu items.
>
> With Advanced Template Manager you have the possibility to assign template styles to just about anything you want, giving you full control over your Joomla template styles.
>
> **Some of its Assignment Options:**
>
> Menu Items, Home Page, Date Range, Templates, URLs, Devices (Mobile, Tablet, Desktop), Operating Systems, Browsers, Components, Tags, Joomla! Content (Assign templates by Joomla Page types, Categories and Articles) and more...

---

In case you want to go the customization way (e.g. overrides, or with a system plugin) you can programmatically assign a template with the following code:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = array();
$app->setTemplate($template_name, $params);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you could do this. Here are two options:

**Option 1:**

Using a category blog.

If we use the news example, do you require the parent category to be a list view (which uses a different template, and listing each article in it's view), with a separate layout view for each article?

To customise the default layout for a category blog in Joomla, you need to create an override for com_content/category (navigate to Extensions -> Templates and overrides from there).

See this post for more info on multiple blog styles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177277/joomla-3-x-category-blog-override-is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one

**Option 2:**

Use Joomla's template styles.

Set these up by assigning Joomla's template styles to a menu item (pointing to your category of choice) and editing your template view in your theme accordingly.

Here's a page from the Joomla docs for reference: 
https://docs.joomla.org/Help37:Extensions_Template_Manager_Styles